# How to convert strings numbers to integers in a list?

Tags: python, string, integer, numbers

I have a list say:

```
['batting average', '306', 'ERA', '1710']
```

How can I convert the intended numbers without touching the strings?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
changed_list = [int(f) if f.isdigit() else f for f in original_list]
```

Comment: An elegant one-liner. Behold the power of list comprehensions.

Comment: was thinking on similar lines

Comment: good solution but what if list has float values also `['batting average', '306', 'ERA', '1710.5']`

Comment: @d.putto added an answer to your question

Answer (score 5):

The data looks like you would know in which positions the numbers are supposed to be. In this case it's probably better to explicitly convert the data at these positions instead of just converting anything that looks like a number:

```
ls = ['batting average', '306', 'ERA', '1710']
ls[1] = int(ls[1])
ls[3] = int(ls[3])
```

Comment: Yep this is the best solution for the static case, while Alex's is best for the dynamic case.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
def convert( someList ):
    for item in someList:
        try:
            yield int(item)
        except ValueError:
            yield item

newList= list( convert( oldList ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a= ['batting average', '306', 'ERA', '1710.5']

[f if sum([c.isalpha() for c in f]) else float(f) for f in a ]
```

if your list contains float, string and int (as pointed about by @d.putto in the comment)

Comment: `sum([c.isalpha() for c in f])` is quite a sub-optimal way to check "if any character in f is alphabetic" - try `any(c.isalpha() for c in f)` for improved readability and performance.  Of course, both will fail if `f` equals for example `'!'` -- a string that's not a number but has no alphanumeric chars -- and also fail to convert e.g `'1.7e3'` -- a string that contains an alphanumeric char but would nevertheless be perfectly fine to pass as the argument to `float` ("exponential notation").

Comment: true. good point...posted it just to answer d.putto's specific contrived example. Should have put in more thought before posting my half baked answer !