# Remove single quotes from python list item

Tags: python, list

Actually quite simple question:
I've a python list like:

```
['1','2','3','4']
```

Just wondering how can I strip those single quotes?
I want `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: do you want to turn the list of strings into a list of ints? To do that just use `[int(x) for x in your_list]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert strings numbers to integers in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818949/how-to-convert-strings-numbers-to-integers-in-a-list)

Comment: Note that this doesn't merely strip the quotes, but changes the list of strings to a list of integers. If you aren't clear on the difference, then you should read about Python's type system.

Comment: There are no quotes in your list, those are strings.  Asking to remove the quotes from your list is like asking to remove the '.' from the value of math.pi. The quotes are there to help show the representation of the data values.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently all of the values in your list are strings, and you want them to integers, here are the two most straightforward ways to do this:

```
map(int, your_list)
```

and

```
[int(value) for value in your_list]
```

See the documentation on [map()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more info.

If you want to leave the items in your list as strings but display them without the single quotes, you can use the following:

```
print('[' + ', '.join(your_list) + ']')
```

Comment: Kudos for showing how to print without the quotes rather than converting the list elements to ints.

Answer (score 5):

If that's an actual python list, and you want `int`s instead of strings, you can just:

```
map(int, ['1','2','3','4'])
```

or

```
[int(x) for x in ['1','2','3','4']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
[int(x) for x in ['1','2','3','4']]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and to play safe you may try

```
[int(x) if type(x) is str else None for x in ['1','2','3','4']]
```

Comment: it's not safe IMO it doesn't throw an exception when it should

Comment: what if the list contains string 'a','b','c','d'