# Lists and Strings PYTHON - beginner

Tags: python, string, list, class, append

I am having issues with formatting and understand lists and strings when it comes to classes.
So I have this code here:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,title):
        self.tile=tile
        self.rank={}

    def addCard(self,compID,number):
        if compID in self.cards and number > self.cards[compID]:
            self.cards[compID]=number
        elif compID not in self.cards:
            self.cards[compID]=number   

    def __str__(self):
        self.cardList = []
        for compID, number in self.cards.items():
            final = compID + "-" + str(number)
            self.cardList.append(temp)
            self.cardList.sort()
        return self.tile + ":" + " " + "Card scores:" + str(self.cardList)
```

so my result looks like this:

```
OUTPUT 1:
Cpt.Fred: Card scores: ['diamond-22', 'hearts-4', 'spades-3']
Lt.Connor: Card scores: ['diamond-43']
```

I am trying to make my result look like this:

```
OUTPUT 2:
Cpt.Fred: Card scores: [ diamond-22, hearts-4, spades-3 ]
Lt.Connor: Card scores: [ diamond-43 ]
```

The data is not whats important, its how to get rid of the " ' " at the beginning and the end of the results. I think it has something to do with my last def() statement but I have been trying to format it every way with no luck. Can anyone help turn the first output to look like the second output?

Comment: I think you're going to have to do some manual list parsing to get it to print how you want. I don't know how to remove those quotes from strings in lists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove single quotes from python list item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419817/remove-single-quotes-from-python-list-item)

Comment: not duplicate: linked question asks for type casting elements of a list, this one is about `str` vs `repr`

Comment: @metaperture, it has nothing to do with casting it is how to remove single quotes from a python list item

Comment: All answers (including the accepted answer) do type casting. There's only a single line on the page about string joins. "Remove single quotes" is the name of the question but apparently everyone took it to mean "convert strs to ints".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `str(self.cardList)`, you should do:

```
return "%s: Card scores: [%s]" % (self.title, ", ".join(self.cardList))
```

The problem is that `str` on a list calls `repr` (includes quotes) on the list's elements, whereas you just want the `str` of the elements joined by commas.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to process and print the list manually. Here's one way you could do that.

```
def printList(cardlist):
  printstr = "["                   # Start with [.
  for card in cardlist:
    printstr += card + ", "        "card, "
  printstr = printstr[:-2] + "]"   # Remove the last ", " before adding the last ].
```

Comment: your for loop can instead be `', '.join(cardlist)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in "str(self.cardList)". It prints out the list as is, meaning it puts strings into quotations to distinguished them from numbers and other objects.

```
def list_to_string(some_list):
    str = "["
    for i in range(len(some_list)):
        str += some_list[i]
        if i < len(some_list)-1:
            str += ", "
    str += "]"
    return str
```

this would parse your list into a string without the quotations